# Can someone help me DRY-ify these ASP.NET MVC Controller ActionResults

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dry

Grabbing the OU of current user and returning a custom model (Division) that has a few properties about the OU.  Then pass it via ViewBag.  My Controller looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult NewAccountRequest()
{
        var currentUser = HttpContext.User;
        var userDivision = ADTools.GetDivisionFromUser(currentUser.Identity.Name);
        ViewBag.UserDivision = userDivision;
        ....
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LookupUNI(string uni)
{
        var currentUser = HttpContext.User;
        var userDivision = ADTools.GetDivisionFromUser(currentUser.Identity.Name);
        ViewBag.UserDivision = userDivision;
        ....
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is common to all of your actions, you could add it to OnActionExecuted for the controller.

```
public void override OnActionExecuted( ActionExecutedContext context )
{
     if (context.Result is ViewResult)
     {
         var currentUser = HttpContext.User;
         var userDivision = ADTools.GetDivisionFromUser(currentUser.Identity.Name);
         ViewBag.UserDivision = userDivision;
     }
}
```